# Stormcrawler XPathFilter - internal representation

Tags: stormcrawler

When Stormcrawler fetches a website, it applies a configured XPathFilter on an HTML representation which is not the original one. E.g.,  tags are inserted, or DIVs will become H3, etc. E.g., the following configuration puts HTML code in Elasticsearch which is not the original one:

```
 {
   "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.ParseFilters": [
   {
   "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.filter.XPathFilter",
   "name": "XPathFilter",
   "params": {
    "canonical": "//*[@rel=\"canonical\"]/@href",
    "parse.html": [
        "//HTML"
     ]
   }
 },
{
  "class": "com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.parse.filter.DomainParseFilter",
  "name": "DomainParseFilter",
  "params": {
    "key": "domain",
    "byHost": false
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

This makes it hard to write XPath Expressions based on the original source code of the website. Is there any way to configure Stormcrawler in a way that it applies the XPathFilter expressions on the original website source code?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of StormCrawler are you on? Are you using Tika for the parsing or Jsoup? AFAIK Jsoup does not modify the content but Tika probably does. I would recommend to use the JSoup-based ParserBolt for HTML content and Tika for anything else.

You can use the [DebugParseFilter](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/wiki/ParseFilters) to see what the DOM looks like.

Comment: We are on 1.10 and use JSoup. The DebugParseFilter provides the same modified output.

Comment: ok, that's unexpected. Would you mind opening an issue on Github with a reproducible test case? Thanks

Comment: Just found on https://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document that there is indeed some normalisation.
https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment could be an alternative

Comment: The DebugParseFilter output looks like a Tika output, but Tika is not used in our stormcrawler configuration. You can easily test this with the default stormcrawler configuration. The easiest way to see the modification are the uppercase element names at websites which originally use lowercase element names.

Comment: Try with 1.12.1, the conversion to DOM has been rewritten since 1.10

Comment: Tried 1.12.1, but still the same behavior. The default elasticsearch flux configuration is used.

Comment: the lowercase -> uppercase is expected, AFAIK this is what XPath expressions should expect. Any other variations, please provide a concrete example in a Github issue. Maybe try changing the code so that parse body fragment is used and see if you are getting anything different from it.

Comment: Is there any way to pass the fetched content directly from the FetcherBolt to the indexing bolt so that the original source code is written into elasticsearch?

Comment: @s_f see https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/ParseSettings.html
this could be configured to preserve tag and attribute case. PLease open an issue in Github if you want this feature.